# Pagecolor after newpage affects pages before newpage

Tags: color, luatex

It seems that using `\pagecolor` after `\newpage` affects pages before `\newpage` in some cases, e.g. floating figures.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\normalpagestyle}{
  \newpage
  \pagecolor{white}
  \color{black}
  \addtokomafont{chapter}{\color{red}\fontsize{16}{16}\selectfont}
}
\newcommand{\specialpagestyle}{
  \newpage
  \pagecolor{red}
  \color{white}
  \addtokomafont{chapter}{\color{white}\fontsize{16}{16}\selectfont}
}
\begin{document}
\normalpagestyle
\chapter{Test}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \rule{10cm}{10cm}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \rule{10cm}{10cm}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \rule{10cm}{10cm}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \rule{10cm}{10cm}
\end{figure}

\specialpagestyle
\blinddocument

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \rule{10cm}{10cm}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \rule{10cm}{10cm}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \rule{10cm}{10cm}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \rule{10cm}{10cm}
\end{figure}
\normalpagestyle
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Is there any way to work around this behaviour?

Comment: Have you tried `\clearpage` instead of `\newpage`?

Comment: just tried it, \clearpage leads to the same result

Comment: sorry, previewed the wrong file after compiling - it actually works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me replacing both instances of `\newpage` with `\clearpage` seems to work:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\normalpagestyle}{
  \clearpage
  \pagecolor{white}
  \color{black}
  \addtokomafont{chapter}{\color{red}\fontsize{16}{16}\selectfont}
}
\newcommand{\specialpagestyle}{
  \clearpage
  \pagecolor{red}
  \color{white}
  \addtokomafont{chapter}{\color{white}\fontsize{16}{16}\selectfont}
}
\begin{document}
\normalpagestyle
\chapter{Test}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \rule{10cm}{10cm}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \rule{10cm}{10cm}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \rule{10cm}{10cm}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \rule{10cm}{10cm}
\end{figure}

\specialpagestyle
\blinddocument

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \rule{10cm}{10cm}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \rule{10cm}{10cm}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \rule{10cm}{10cm}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \rule{10cm}{10cm}
\end{figure}
\normalpagestyle
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Skillmon has already said how to fix the issue, but to explain what is happening, `\pagecolor` does not affect earlier pages, rather the figures are being inserted after the page colour has changed.

You have `[ht]` so the floats are not allowed on a float page they are only allowed on pages that also contain text. As you have no text they are all being stacked in the queue waiting to have some pages on which they may be placed.

The `\specialpagestye` then changes the page colour to red, but still not floats have been inserted into the document.

Then finally the `\chapter` issues a `\clearpage`, unlike `\newpage` `\clearpage` flushes all floats as an emergency operation effectively forcing `p` into their optional placement and ignoring all constraints. So all the floats up to that point are then output (but the page is already red).

In older latex releases if you stacked up floats in this way you would get an error if you used more than 18 "no room for a new float"  but recent releases use etex extended registers and so you can stack up several thousand floats without hitting that error.